# Ethereum Stack Exchange Spring Challenge 2016

Tags: discussion, voting, badges, challenge

I'm willing to put up a bounty to any user on here to earn the [Electorate Badge](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate) and [Civic Duty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) until end of Mai of 2016. This is basicly the most easy-to-get gold badge available on stack exchange and currently only eth and myself hold one. Let's change this. The rules are simple and there are only two:

- Earn the [Electorate Badge](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate) badge during the months of April or Mai 2016
- Earn the [Civic Duty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) badge during the month of Mai 2016
- Have at least one answer on any question (needed to award the points*)

I am willing to put up 50xp of my points to anyone who makes the grade. You don't even have to acknowledge you are shooting for this, just show up and vote**. You can keep track of how many votes you've cast by looking at the bottom of your user page under the activity tab:

[image: profile screenshot]

This is the number you're looking at and it needs to equal 600. When you upvote a question this number will increase.

So basically how do you get it? Upvote questions and it's all yours. Let's get out the vote!! :D

***NOTE 1**: Please make sure your answer I award on is a good one, if you only have a crap answer, I'll hold the points until you have a good one worthy of the points :-)

***NOTE 2**: Down-votes also count, this is no challenge to randomly push bad content. Make your votes count where they fit best. Maybe [start reviewing content here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes).

> Shamelessly adapted from [mechanics stack exchange meta](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/).
>
> Crossposted on reddit [r/ethereum](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4gi34p/ask_and_answer_questions_on_ethereum_stack/).

**Update 1**: Also [Civic Duty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) is up for a reward now.

Comment: now wouldn't it be good if I noticed this last Month instead of now! :o)

Comment: you somehow did manage to get it in-time. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [zanzu](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/124/zanzu), [Nicolas Massart](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/405/nicolas-massart) and [tayvano](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/300/tayvano) for making the [Civic Duty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) badge in the last minute. ;-)

No [Electorate](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate) badge was claimed. Next time I will announce a longer time frame. :-)

Comment: does this happen every year?

Comment: No, this is a manual process :)